# Print page, hide page title/number and add top padding

Tags: print-css

I am working on a print CSS. What I would like to do is hide the page title/number that gets put on each page, and add some top padding to each page. To get rid of the page title/number I am using `margin:0;` which works well, but the `padding-top:30px;` doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```css
@page { 
    size:8.5in 11in;  
    margin:0;
    padding-top:30px;
    orphans:5; 
    widows:5;
}

.page-break {
    page-break-after:always;
    margin:0!important;
    padding:0!important;
    font-size:0!important;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus interdum odio. Duis vel volutpat quam, sed feugiat diam. Fusce vulputate tellus ut leo iaculis ultrices. Sed ultrices odio ut lobortis bibendum. Vestibulum sed sodales leo. Mauris ullamcorper aliquam lorem, efficitur sagittis ex auctor a. In mattis mauris vitae diam rhoncus auctor.</p>

<p class="page-break"></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus interdum odio. Duis vel volutpat quam, sed feugiat diam. Fusce vulputate tellus ut leo iaculis ultrices. Sed ultrices odio ut lobortis bibendum. Vestibulum sed sodales leo. Mauris ullamcorper aliquam lorem, efficitur sagittis ex auctor a. In mattis mauris vitae diam rhoncus auctor.</p>

<p class="page-break"></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus interdum odio. Duis vel volutpat quam, sed feugiat diam. Fusce vulputate tellus ut leo iaculis ultrices. Sed ultrices odio ut lobortis bibendum. Vestibulum sed sodales leo. Mauris ullamcorper aliquam lorem, efficitur sagittis ex auctor a. In mattis mauris vitae diam rhoncus auctor.</p>

<p class="page-break"></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus interdum odio. Duis vel volutpat quam, sed feugiat diam. Fusce vulputate tellus ut leo iaculis ultrices. Sed ultrices odio ut lobortis bibendum. Vestibulum sed sodales leo. Mauris ullamcorper aliquam lorem, efficitur sagittis ex auctor a. In mattis mauris vitae diam rhoncus auctor.</p>

<p class="page-break"></p>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec finibus interdum odio. Duis vel volutpat quam, sed feugiat diam. Fusce vulputate tellus ut leo iaculis ultrices. Sed ultrices odio ut lobortis bibendum. Vestibulum sed sodales leo. Mauris ullamcorper aliquam lorem, efficitur sagittis ex auctor a. In mattis mauris vitae diam rhoncus auctor.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use the `.page-break` to do this?

```
.page-break {
  page-break-after: always;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

(I removed the `!important`s for clarity. Do you really need them?)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to have an effect on the page that comes after the page break. The content is still hugging the top of the page.

Comment: I was able to figure out a solution based on your answer. Instead of using `page-break-after`, I am now using `page-break-before` with a top margin instead of bottom and it is working as desired. Thanks!